# CNCopySupportedInterfaces() returning no value although wifi connected

Tags: ios, xcode, reachability, captivenetwork, bssid

I am using CNCopySupportedInterfaces() to get bssid and it is not returning any value. Not sure why.

My code looks like this:

```
    #import <SystemConfiguration/CaptiveNetwork.h>

    CFArrayRef myArray = CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
    CFDictionaryRef myDict = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(myArray, 0));
    NSLog(@"Connected at:%@",myDict);
    NSDictionary *myDictionary = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary*)myDict;
    NSString * BSSID = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"BSSID"];
    NSLog(@"bssid is %@",BSSID);
```

NSLog(@"%@",CNCopySupportedInterfaces());

returns (null)

Not sure what is wrong? Need some guidance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just figured out it this code does not work in ios6.. working fine in ios5.. it doesn't work in simulator. Try in the device.

Comment: Works find for me on my iOS 6 and iOS 7 (beta) devices. Not in simulator.

Comment: dun use simulator. this need to use device.

Comment: I'm use iphone 5S os 7.1 it not working,
 CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(myArray, 0)) return null

Answer (score 2):

To use `CNCopySupportedInterfaces` you must enable **Access WiFi Information** capability in the Capabilities pane of your project settings.

Comment: This is true, iOS 12 requires app to turn on this Entitlement. (Apart from the simulator issue)